# Symfony 3 Form for insert Array in my database

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to insert data into the array of my entity using a form but it's doesn't works

Example:

> Text Field 1: i write "Prog"
>   Text Field 2: i write "Kille"
>   Text
>   Field 3: i write "Papa"

What i need to have in my database:
Category: a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Prog";i:1;s:5:"Kille";i:2;s:4:"Papa";}

Form:

```
    $builder->add('category', CollectionType::class, array(
'entry_type' => TextType::class,
'allow_add' => true,
'prototype' => true,
'prototype_data' => 'New Tag Placeholder' ));
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="array")
 */
private $category;
```

Twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But it's show nothing on my website, only the label "Category".
I search during some hour and now i don't know how to do.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add text boxes using JavaScript. An example is available in the Symfony documentation.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items